Setting up a rolling 2 week filter in MS Project, missing the "Weekday" function
I want to set up a rolling 2 week look ahead filter in MS Project.  I know how to add 14 days to today using now() + 14 however it would be better if it use the date of the Friday in 2 weeks time.  Hence if I was to run it today (10th June) it would show tasks which started before Friday 28th June.  I would also show the same tasks if I was to run it on the 11th, 12th ... 14th.   This has two advantages - 1) it fits with how the business people think and 2) it allows me to run the report at any time.
I know I can set a filter which asks for a date but it would be nice if it did some of the thinking for the user.
I would prefer to avoid VBA if at all possible.
Thanks
Miles

Step 1
The key to getting the 'next Friday date' regardless of what the current date is, is to use the DatePart function which returns a value of 1-7 using "w" for the interval argument.
This formula will return the Friday 2 weeks out regardless of the current date. Current date = June 10 --> returns June 28. Current date June 14 --> June 28, but current date June 15 --> July 5. When the date rolls to the next week is controlled by the third argument 'firstdayofweek'. In this case we use Saturday (7).
DateAdd("d", 21 - DatePart("w", Date(), 7), Date())

Step 2
The second part is to set up a custom Flag field with this formula. Note that the formula is shifted one day so that the inequality reads "finish before Saturday 2 weeks out" since dates in Project always have a time component and to say "Finish <= Friday" would miss all tasks finishing on that Friday since Friday 5:00 PM > Friday 12:00 AM.
IIf([Finish]<DateAdd("d",22-DatePart("w",Date(),7),Date()),"yes","no")


And finally, filter on that Flag field.
